# nsurlconnection is by default what ? Synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

```
NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://google.com"]];
NSURLConnection * connect = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
[connect start];
```

is this synchronous or asynchronous ??? NSURLConnection is by default which 1 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which method you calling in NSURLConnection. But most of the method are related asynchronous. Except one that is sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:

Loading Data Synchronously

```
+ sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:
```

Loading Data Asynchronously

```
+ connectionWithRequest:delegate:
– initWithRequest:delegate:
– initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:
+ sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:
– start
```

Comment: how do i fire a nsurlconnection on the main thread ?? 
And how do i do it the background ??

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate it this way, you are invoking the asynchronous, delegate-based implementation.

Note, if you call `initWithRequest:delegate:`, you should not call `start`. That is only used if you call `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` with `NO` for that final parameter. The rendition without that `startImmediately` parameter automatically starts the connection for you.

Comment: how do i fire a nsurlconnection on the main thread ?? 
And how do i do it the background ??

Comment: If you fire `NSURLConnection` on the main thread, just make sure you do it asynchronously (e.g. with `initWithRequest:delegate:`). As long as you do that asynchronously, there is no need to run it on background thread yourself. But if you are on background thread and have to start connection, you would use `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` with `NO` for that final parameter, then manually schedule it on main run loop, and then manually `start` it. But you only have to do that if you're starting it on background thread, which is not typical.

Answer (score 1):

NSURLConnection API can be synchronous or asynchronous depending on how you use it while the NSURLSession API is asynchronous.

In the above case it is asynchronous.

Comment: how do i fire a nsurlconnection on the main thread ?? 
And how do i do it the background ??

Comment: Its is not recommended to load it on the Main Thread, it will block the UI - This is possible via + sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:   .Unless absolutely essential Use the asynchronous method that Sivajee has in his answer.